# How do I fix very slow scrolling USB wheel mouse (after waking from suspend) which started after upgrade to 19.04?

Tags: usb, suspend, 19.04, mouse-scroll

This morning before I upgraded when I rolled the scroll wheel any active program would scroll as long as the wheel was turning.  After upgrade to 19.04 after waking from suspend (closing the laptop) when I roll the wheel the view scrolls a few lines then stops, it won't scroll again until I spin the scroll wheel a few more times.

Microsoft Wireless Mobile Mouse 4000

It happens in every program including a virtual-box boot up of Windows, and only seems to be after waking from suspend. Unplugging the USB receiver and plugging it back in restores the sensitivity but to me that isn't a fix, jsut a work around.

How do I stop whatever system behavior in suspend which is disrupting the mouse settings? How do I restore it without physical intervention (automatically on wake up if possible)

And why did the upgrade break it, or could it be that much of a coincidence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## ResetMsMice

A special program has been released to reset Microsoft Mice when dual booting Windows and Linux experiences insanely fast scrolling. It has just been confirmed to work for Ubuntu 19.04 suspend/resume problem of insanely slow scrolling.

Go to this site: https://sourceforge.net/projects/resetmsmice/

Click the link for: `resetmsmice_1.1.3_amd64.deb`

It is instantly downloaded to your `~/Downloads` folder.

To install it use:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/resetmsmice_1.1.3_amd64.deb
rm -f ~/Downloads/resetmsmice_1.1.3_amd64.deb
```

The program automatically runs during boot but you can also call it from the terminal at any time with:

```
resetmsmice
```

To automatically call it after resuming you need to create a script with `gedit`.

Use `sudo -H gedit /lib/systemd/system-sleep/resetmsmice`

Copy these lines into the editor:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
case $1/$2 in
  pre/*)
    echo "$0: Going to $2..."
        ;;
  post/*)
    echo "$0: Waking up from $2..."
    resetmsmice
        ;;
esac
```

The `echo` statements help you locate your program in system logs, eg `grep resetmsmice` Save the file and exit the editor. Then use:

```bash
sudo chmod a+x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/resetmsmice
```

---

## Original Answer

You can power off the USB mouse during suspend and power it on during resume. This will simulate a reboot.

Use `sudo -H gedit /lib/systemd/system-sleep/custom-xhci_hcd`

Copy these lines into the editor:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Original script was using /bin/sh but shellcheck reporting warnings.

# NAME: custom-xhci_hcd
# PATH: /lib/systemd/system-sleep
# CALL: Called from SystemD automatically
# DESC: Suspend broken for USB3.0 as of Oct 25/2018 various kernels all at once

# DATE: Oct 28 2018.

# NOTE: From comment #61 at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/522998

TMPLIST=/tmp/xhci-dev-list

# Original script was: case "${1}" in hibernate|suspend)

case $1/$2 in
  pre/*)
    echo "$0: Going to $2..."
    echo -n '' > $TMPLIST
          for i in `ls /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/ | egrep '[0-9a-z]+\:[0-9a-z]+\:.*$'`; do
              # Unbind xhci_hcd for first device XXXX:XX:XX.X:
               echo -n "$i" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/unbind
           echo "$i" >> $TMPLIST
          done
        ;;
  post/*)
    echo "$0: Waking up from $2..."
    for i in `cat $TMPLIST`; do
              # Bind xhci_hcd for first device XXXX:XX:XX.X:
              echo -n "$i" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/bind
    done
    rm $TMPLIST
        ;;
esac
```

Save the file and exit the editor. Then use:

```bash
sudo chmod a+x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/custom-xhci_hcd
```

---

Ubuntu 19.04 upgrade delivers the new Linux 5.0 kernel with new drivers. After future upgrades are done, deactivate the script to see if the problem has been fixed in new kernels.

Comment: Tried it and double checked everything to the best of my ability but I don't see any difference.  Is there a way I can check what I'm doing.

Comment: @Dennis Sure. Do a suspend and resume. Then use `journalctl -xe` which will bring you to end of system messages then page up. You'll see the system suspend and resume messages. Look for `custom-xhci_hcd` and you should see USB devices being turn off during suspend and turned on during resume. If there is an error message instead (or it doesn't appear) let me know. If you need more clarification I'll update answer with example of reading system log.

Comment: There is a reference to the custom-xhci_hcd with no errors near it, several lines that look like  usb 2-1.2: reset full-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci prior to the reference to it. The mouse works fine in every respect except the speed of the scroll wheel until I re-insert the receiver.

Comment: @Dennis Turns out there are many bugs reported with Microsoft Mice when dual booting and when resuming. There are also many fixes published. Here is one that might be inserted into the script I posted above: https://sourceforge.net/projects/resetmsmice/ Also a related problem with Microsoft Mouse and 19.04 was posted today: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140117/mouse-scroll-needs-17-ticks-to-register-1-movement-on-fresh-ubuntu-19-04

Comment: Yes that post sounds like mine.  Though I don't dual boot the resetmsmice does solve the problem and can be run from the command line. Running at each resume is necessary for me because the "on boot" setting doesn't do anything for resume, but at least I don't have to unplug it each time.  If you want to at that as an "if the script doesn't work, try...." in your answer I'll accept that as the best available option.

Comment: @Dennis I added `resetmsmice` to the top of the answer.

Comment: I'm curious about whether your answer is relevant to my question: https://askubuntu.com/q/1454673/48214 and also how to make it fully automatic so that I don't need to run a command each time after waking the computer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Turn off and on the mouse or unplug and plug in the cable.

Comment: I DIDN'T try turning it on and off again. Thanks so much  @Jonatan Öström not only did you fix my day, you made me laugh out loud!

Answer (score 0):

my scroll wheel will stop functioning just moving from a new tab in chrome or another app to a tab i've had open in chrome for a while.  I can refresh the page and mouse wheel scrolling works again.  The scroll bars to the right always work.

Using chrome stable
ubuntu 19.04

Comment: Is this an issue, or a solution?