# Lapop won't wake from suspend

Tags: nvidia, suspend, dell, xps, 19.04

I've just installed Disco on my Dell xps 15 9570 after trying manjaro, and I'm quite liking it, but I'm having a big problem with suspend.

If I shut the lid or leave it alone for too long and try to it nothing happens, it seems the display backlight comes on, but it still remains black. To wake it I've tried pressing keys and wiggling the mouse as well as taping the power button, but to no avail, all that's working so far is to completely turn it off and restart, meaning I lose whatever I was working on.

I've also tried looking for a `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` file as I saw somewhere else, but I don't have one, here's the directory it should be in:

```
$ ls /var/log
alternatives.log  dmesg           gdm3                    openvpn
apt               dmesg.0         gpu-manager.log         private
auth.log          dmesg.1.gz      gpu-manager-switch.log  speech-dispatcher
boot.log          dmesg.2.gz      hp                      syslog
bootstrap.log     dmesg.3.gz      installer               unattended-upgrades
btmp              dpkg.log        journal                 wtmp
cups              faillog         kern.log                Xorg.0.log
dist-upgrade      fontconfig.log  lastlog                 Xorg.0.log.old
```

Nvidia x server settings are set to use the Nvidia GPU over the Intel one

```
**System info**
OS version: 19.04
Kernel: 5.0.0-13-generic
Gnome: 3.32.1
CPU: Intel® Core™ i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz × 12 
GPU: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti with Max-Q Design/PCIe/SSE2
Nvidia driver: 418.56
```

dmesg output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/PtF2r427Qv/

thanks for any help!

**Edit:** here's the end of `journalctl -b-1`

```
Apr 29 18:58:13 roshan-XPS gnome-keyring-daemon[1528]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/1, but it's already registered
Apr 29 18:58:13 roshan-XPS systemd-logind[872]: Power key pressed.
Apr 29 18:58:15 roshan-XPS colord[953]: failed to get session [pid 868]: No data available
Apr 29 18:58:15 roshan-XPS systemd-resolved[792]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level 
Apr 29 18:58:16 roshan-XPS systemd-resolved[792]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level 
Apr 29 18:58:16 roshan-XPS systemd-logind[872]: Power key pressed.
Apr 29 18:58:18 roshan-XPS colord[953]: failed to get session [pid 868]: No data available
Apr 29 18:58:19 roshan-XPS systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
Apr 29 18:58:19 roshan-XPS systemd-resolved[792]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level 
Apr 29 18:58:22 roshan-XPS systemd-logind[872]: Power key pressed.
Apr 29 18:58:26 roshan-XPS systemd-logind[872]: Power key pressed.
Apr 29 18:58:28 roshan-XPS gsd-power[1793]: Error setting property 'PowerSaveMode' on interface org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
Apr 29 18:58:28 roshan-XPS gsd-power[1793]: Error setting property 'PowerSaveMode' on interface org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
Apr 29 18:58:29 roshan-XPS ModemManager[862]: <info>  [device /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7] creating modem with plugin 'Generic' and '1' ports
Apr 29 18:58:29 roshan-XPS ModemManager[862]: <warn>  Could not grab port (tty/ttyACM0): 'Cannot add port 'tty/ttyACM0', unhandled serial type'
Apr 29 18:58:29 roshan-XPS ModemManager[862]: <warn>  Couldn't create modem for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7': Failed to find primary AT port
Apr 29 18:58:39 roshan-XPS gsd-power[1793]: Failed to acquire idle monitor proxy: Timeout was reached
Apr 29 18:58:39 roshan-XPS gsd-power[1793]: Failed to acquire idle monitor proxy: Timeout was reached
Apr 29 18:58:39 roshan-XPS gsd-power[1793]: Failed to acquire idle monitor proxy: Timeout was reached
Apr 29 18:58:41 roshan-XPS gsd-power[1793]: Failed to acquire idle monitor proxy: Timeout was reached
Apr 29 18:58:41 roshan-XPS gsd-power[1793]: Failed to acquire idle monitor proxy: Timeout was reached
Apr 29 18:58:41 roshan-XPS gsd-power[1793]: Failed to acquire idle monitor proxy: Timeout was reached
Apr 29 18:58:41 roshan-XPS gnome-session[1547]: gnome-session-binary[1547]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Failed to acquire idle monitor proxy: Timeout was reached
Apr 29 18:58:41 roshan-XPS gnome-session-binary[1547]: GnomeDesktop-WARNING: Failed to acquire idle monitor proxy: Timeout was reached
Apr 29 18:58:44 roshan-XPS gsd-power[1793]: Error setting property 'PowerSaveMode' on interface org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
Apr 29 18:58:49 roshan-XPS CRON[4760]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 29 18:58:49 roshan-XPS CRON[4761]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi)
Apr 29 18:58:49 roshan-XPS CRON[4760]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Apr 29 18:58:49 roshan-XPS CRON[4762]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 29 18:58:49 roshan-XPS CRON[4763]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi)
Apr 29 18:58:49 roshan-XPS CRON[4762]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

As you can see there appears to be a fair bit of entries mentioning monitors or desktops, but I'm not sure what to make of that?

Comment: Try `prime-select intel` and reboot. See if suspend works. Use `prime-slect nvidia` and reboot to restore Nvidia GPU.

Comment: using the intel GPU does seem to have solved the issue, although it's a little disappointing

Comment: Don't feel disappointed. We've ruled out the Nvidia GPU as being the problem and can move on to the next step. The last time my laptop wouldn't suspend / resume properly I wrote a script to power off all USB devices during suspend and power them back on during resume. This accomplishes unplugging all USB devices as the answer below suggests without having to physically unplug them: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1136187/how-do-i-fix-very-slow-scrolling-usb-wheel-mouse-after-waking-from-suspend-whi/1138030#1138030

Comment: I am having the same problem. I tried `prime-select intel` and rebooted. Then tried to suspend and wake up. The first few tries went OK. The third one did not went OK. I guess, this time I waited longer after it was suspended and during suspend a program was doing network and disk IO. The same happens when you select `nvidia` though: It sometimes works; but generally it does not wake up. In such cases even REISUB [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key] does not reboot your machine; you have to hard power down and up.

Answer (score 0):

```
[    0.311997] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS01._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.312005] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.312007] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.312009] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS01._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.312012] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.312014] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.312400] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS02._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.312403] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.312405] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.312407] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS02._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.312409] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.312411] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.312788] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS03._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.312791] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.312792] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.312794] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS03._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.312797] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.312798] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.313175] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS04._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.313179] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.313180] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.313182] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS04._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.313184] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.313186] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.313561] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS05._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.313564] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.313565] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.313567] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS05._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.313569] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.313571] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.313951] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS06._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.313954] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.313956] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.313957] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS06._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.313960] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.313961] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.314337] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS07._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.314340] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.314341] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.314343] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS07._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.314345] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.314347] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.314722] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS08._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.314725] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.314726] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.314728] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS08._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.314731] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.314732] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.315107] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS09._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.315110] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.315112] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.315113] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS09._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.315116] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.315117] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.315494] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS10._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.315497] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.315498] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.315500] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS10._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.315502] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.315504] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.315878] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS11._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.315881] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.315883] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.315884] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS11._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.315887] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.315888] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.316264] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS12._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.316267] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.316268] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.316270] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS12._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.316272] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.316274] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.316674] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.USR1._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.316677] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.316679] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.316680] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.USR1._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.316683] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.316684] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.316688] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.USR2._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.316690] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.316692] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.316693] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.USR2._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.316696] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.316697] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.316739] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS01._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.316742] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.316743] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.316745] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS01._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.316747] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.316749] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.316790] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS02._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.316793] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.316794] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.316796] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS02._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.316798] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.316800] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.316840] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS03._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.316843] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.316845] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.316846] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS03._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.316849] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.316850] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.316890] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS04._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.316893] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.316895] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.316896] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS04._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.316899] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.316900] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.316941] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS05._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.316943] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.316945] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.316946] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS05._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.316949] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.316950] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.316991] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS06._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.316994] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.316995] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.316996] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS06._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.316999] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.317000] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.317041] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS07._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.317044] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.317045] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.317046] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS07._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.317049] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.317050] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.317091] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS08._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.317094] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.317095] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.317097] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS08._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.317099] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.317101] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.317141] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS09._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.317144] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.317146] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.317147] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS09._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.317150] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.317151] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.317191] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS10._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.317194] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.317196] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.317197] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS10._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.317200] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.317201] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.323241] ACPI: 13 ACPI AML tables successfully acquired and loaded
[    0.350418] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored

[    1.338128] tpm_tis MSFT0101:00: 2.0 TPM (device-id 0xFC, rev-id 1)
[    1.339919] tpm tpm0: A TPM error (2314) occurred attempting the self test

[  208.756162] pci_raw_set_power_state: 27 callbacks suppressed
[  208.756163] pcieport 0000:03:02.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
[  208.756385] xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
[  208.833917] xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
[  208.833959] xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: WARN: xHC restore state timeout
[  208.833962] xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: PCI post-resume error -110!
[  208.833966] xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: HC died; cleaning up
[  208.833993] xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: remove, state 4
[  208.834002] usb usb4: USB disconnect, device number 1
[  208.834379] xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: USB bus 4 deregistered
[  208.834388] xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: remove, state 4
[  208.834394] usb usb3: USB disconnect, device number 1
[  208.834735] xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: Host halt failed, -19
[  208.834742] xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: Host not accessible, reset failed.
[  208.834888] xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: USB bus 3 deregistered
[  208.835288] pcieport 0000:03:01.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
[  209.335992] pci_bus 0000:04: busn_res: [bus 04] is released
[  209.336025] pci_bus 0000:05: busn_res: [bus 05-39] is released
[  209.336078] pci_bus 0000:3a: busn_res: [bus 3a] is released
[  209.336104] pci_bus 0000:03: busn_res: [bus 03-3a] is released
```

First, update this:
[Dell XPS 15 9570 System BIOS](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=wghf7&oscode=wt64a&productcode=xps-15-9570-laptop)

[Dell Driver Thunderbolt 3 Firmware Update](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=5xg11&oscode=wt64a&productcode=xps-15-9570-laptop)

Then disable fast boot, secure boot, TPM device encryption, and thunderbolt encryption in the uefi/bios.  Then remove whatever usb 3/xHCI devices you have attached to that thing.

Then test again.

Comment: It should be pointed out to reboot into Windows 10 in order to install the firmware drivers.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I though some of the newer dells could do firmware updates in Linux?

Comment: @CharlesGreen I read that too but haven't been brave enough to test it myself. My last Dell update was for 10 firmware drivers and I did it in Windows 10. Regardless this answer links to Windows 10 drivers. The primary reason I keep Windows 10 is for gaming the secondary is for driver updates.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2UnixNo Windows on my system - and bios is tough as a result.  I have made Win8 boot disks in the past and run that way...

Comment: @Jack unfortunately I don't have windows installed anymore, although I made sure to update all the firmware before I removed it, so that shouldn't be a problem unless you can see something that suggests otherwise? I'll try the rest of the suggestions when I next reboot

Comment: @CharlesGreen The dell drivers can also be installed from DOS which I'm sure you can easily boot from Grub. I might setup DOS from Grub myself some day as I have tons of old DOS programs kicking around.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2UnixFor some reason my older dell will only update under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

### NVMe SSD likely culprit

You have a ton of `ACPI` errors which should be of concern. However the most likely cause is the NVMe SSD. Use `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` and change this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpiphp.disable=1"
```

you might have extra options but inserting `acpiphp.disable=1` is the most important. It prevents the SSD from powering off by itself (or something like that).

Save the file and then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

After your next reboot your problems will hopefully be solved. If not the cause is likely to be the many `ACPI` errors in your boot log.

---

### ACPI errors

Your boot log is being spammed with the same two ACPI error messages repeated:

```
[    0.311997] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS01._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.312005] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.312007] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.312009] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS01._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.312012] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.312014] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.312400] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS02._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.312403] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.312405] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
[    0.312407] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS02._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.312409] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.312411] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)
```

In contrast I only have single ACPI error group which is a [common bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1584407):

```
Apr 27 09:41:08 alien kernel: ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.XHC_.RHUB.HS11] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170728/dswload-210)
Apr 27 09:41:08 alien kernel: ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20170728/psobject-252)
Apr 27 09:41:08 alien kernel: ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, (SSDT:xh_rvp10) while loading table (20170728/tbxfload-228)
Apr 27 09:41:08 alien kernel: ACPI Error: 1 table load failures, 9 successful (20170728/tbxfload-246)
```

Because ACPI error messages in boot log are so common I wouldn't focus my attention there first.

### Viewing previous boot

You might want to set up `journalctl` to be persistent across boots:

- [How to find previous boot log after Ubuntu 16.04+ restarts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765315/how-to-find-previous-boot-log-after-ubuntu-16-04-restarts)

It makes it easier to see exactly where your machine died and what killed it by using:

```
journalctl -b-1
```

This brings up the previous boot that died with suspend / not resume / power switch. Tapping the <kbd>End</kbd> key takes you from the first boot messages immediately down to the last messages before freeze up.

Comment: I've tried the acpiphp disable bit, but it doesn't seem to have solved the issue at all unfortunatley I've added extra info to my question

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the `mem_sleep_default`, known issue with Dell XPS 13, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029474/ubuntu-18-04-dell-xps13-9370-no-longer-suspends-on-lid-close). I had the same issue with my Dell XPS 15.
Whats the output of `cat /sys/power/mem_sleep`? should be:
s2idel [deep]
If it is not change `/etc/default/grub`:
change the line
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
to
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash mem_sleep_default=deep"`
For more details see the provided link.

Comment: I tested `mem_sleep_default=deep` and rebooted/restarted, but it did not change anything. By the way, `/sys/power/mem_sleep` was already `s2idle [deep]`.