# GNOME desktop freezes when laptop lid is closed

Tags: gnome, suspend, power-management, laptop, screensaver

I am aware this issue has been asked before, but I have tried the common solutions like changing `HandleLidSwitch=Ignore` and removing GNOME screensaver and installing `xscreensaver` with no splash.

I am trying to use my laptop with two monitors and currently have the laptop set up so the internal screen is off. This setup works fine when I leave the lid open; but the open windows stop responding when I close the lid, although the cursor still moves and some tasks can still be performed (e.g. dragging windows).

Laptop is a Dell E7240.

Version: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138957/lapop-wont-wake-from-suspend I have as similar problem also, with no solution so far.

Comment: I have disabled the lid switch at a kernel level by adding the node corresponding to the lid switch, found using cat /proc/acpi/wakeup, to /sys/bus/acpi/drivers/button/unbind. 

This has solved the issue with the screens reversing and clearly the kernel is now ignoring lid switching. However, it seems GNOME is still detecting the switch event and freezing after a few seconds.

Comment: This still remains unanswered, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workable solution found:

[Screenshot of finding LID node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OrgF.png)

1) Find lid switch node with

```
cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

2) Unbind by echoing that node into the directory:

*/sys/bus/acpi/drivers/button/unbind*

3) Close lid

4) Restart display manager after lid close:

```
sudo systemctl restart display-manager
```

Comment: Don't think I am ready to mark this as solved yet though since figuring out how to stop x-server detecting lid changes would be ideal