# Black screen with cursor after suspend

Tags: 20.04, suspend

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and after waking up from suspend I get a black screen with a cursor.

I've run `update` and `upgrade` and it didn't fix the problem. I tried switching to lightdm but the problem is the same.
I tried pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>alt</kbd> +<kbd>f1</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>alt</kbd> +<kbd>f3</kbd> and nothing happens. I'm on a laptop so I've tried using <kbd>fn</kbd> too, but still nothing.

The only thing that seems to work is holding down the power button to stop the machine.

Comment: Similar problems: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148022 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138957

Comment: I have the same issue after lock screen nothing work only black screen mouse and keyboard lights are off too, It happened suddenly may be new update cause this, only solution so far is to hard restart

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently this was a bug in the Nvidia driver. The new version specifically fixes this problem, but it is only available on Nvidia's website as of yet.

Comment: could you share the link where you downloaded the driver?

Comment: @AdnanMujkanovic Sure, it's from here https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/unix/

Answer (score 3):

When the black screen appears, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd>/<kbd>Break</kbd> multiple times and then some help appears.

Also, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> allows rebooting without pressing the power button.

I know that's not much of a help, but it is something.