# Ubuntu 19.04 freezes after suspending, only unfreezes after subsequently closing the lid

Tags: mouse, suspend, power-management, laptop, 19.04

My laptop is running Ubuntu 19.04. When I'm waking it up after it got suspended, it often freezes - I can't move the mouse pointer and typing on the keyboard (Esc or Enter) results in nothing.

Only when I then close the lid and leave it closed for about 10 seconds before opening it again can I move the mouse/press Enter to be shown the password dialog.

Are there any logs that can show me what is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: A similar (or identical) problem was discussed in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138957/lapop-wont-wake-from-suspend . You can try the proposed workarounds / solutions given there. I have the same problem you described and I haven't found a solution yet. I just disabled the lid switch and any other suspend actions in Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you very much, I searched but did not see this one. I'll update if anything worked.