# Mouse scroll needs 17 ticks to register 1 movement on fresh Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: kernel, mouse, 19.04, scrolling, microsoft

This was not an issue with Ubuntu 18.04.

When on Ubuntu 19.04 which I just installed fresh I noticed it even already using the LiveCD.

I have only found this problem using **Microsoft Standard Optical Mouse**.

A generic cheap USB mouse had no trouble scrolling as expected.

I've tried rebooting and other USB 2.0 and 3.0 ports.

I also experienced the same issue on the latest **Fedora 30** so maybe it could be related to **kernel modules** ?

```bsh
$ uname -a
Linux 5.0.0-13-generic #14-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 15 14:59:14 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```bsh
$ xinput list

⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft Wireless Optical Desktop® 2.10    id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft Wireless Optical Desktop® 2.10    id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft Wireless Optical Desktop® 2.10    id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

```bsh
$ xinput list-props 11
Device 'Microsoft Microsoft Wireless Optical Desktop® 2.10':
    Device Enabled (163):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (165): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (300):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (301):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (302):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (303):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (304):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (305): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (306): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (307):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (308):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (309): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (310): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (311):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (312):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (313):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (314): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (315): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (285): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (286):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (287):    0, 0
    Device Node (288):  "/dev/input/event5"
    Device Product ID (289):    1118, 157
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (316):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (317):   1
```

Comment: See comment thread at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1136187/how-do-i-fix-very-slow-scrolling-usb-wheel-mouse-after-waking-from-suspend-whi    Best solution I could find so far was the resetmsmice linked in the comments to the first answer.

Comment: @Dennis for me the resetmsmice solution doesn't work. I don't have to suspend/wake the computer for the problem to start so I believe this is something new.

Comment: `resetmsmice` also works when you first boot or reboot your computer. That is why the program was originally written. It was a bonus that it fixes suspend/resume mouse problems for @Dennis too.

Comment: It's a shame that resetmsmice doesn't work for this case. I also didn't feel the need to use such tool to fix the scrolling when in the previous kernel when using Ubuntu 18.04. The Linux kernel is probably the cause of the problem.